# Smooth transition on scroll after adding header on scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a `header` which:

- Displays on default (transparent background)
- When user scrolls down the page (25px), it will add the `header--maroon` class to `header` - which it does. The `header-maroon` class basically adds the background color and anchor styles.
- But at this point (when the user has scrolled 25px down the page), I want the `header` to "fade up" smoothly and basically stay hidden when the user is scrolling down.
- Lastly, when a user scrolls (10px) up the page, I want the `header` to fade in neatly at the top of the viewpoint.

Here's my current approach. It kind of works, but not as smooth as I'd like (as in the the header just appears, I want it to transition in). I have tried to add transitions, but it doesn't work?

```js
/**********/
/* SCROLL */
/**********/

//Add transition when scrolling down
$(window).scroll(function() {    
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 25) {
      $("header").addClass("header--maroon");
  } else {
      $("header").removeClass("header--maroon");
  }
});

// add scroll effect on page refresh too
$(function() { 
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 10) {
    $(".mainMenu").addClass("header--maroon");
  } else {
    $(".mainMenu").removeClass("header--maroon");
  }
});

/******************************/
/* HIDE HEADER ON SCROLL DOWN */
/******************************/

var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 25;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
        }
    }
    
    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

```css
body{
  background: wheat;
  height:1000px;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background: transparent;
}

.nav-up {
  top: -90px;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.header--maroon {
  background: #521717;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.mainMenu {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header class="nav-down">
  <div class="mainMenu">Link</div>
</header>

<div class="gap"></div>
```

Comment: transition: background-color 1000ms linear;

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing this:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mariusc23/s6mLJ/31/)

HTML:

```
<header class="nav-down">
    This is your menu.
</header>
<main>
    This is your body.
</main>
<footer>
    This is your footer.
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

header {
    background: #f5b335;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-up {
    top: -40px;
}

main {
 background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAPklEQVQYV2O8dOnSfwYg0NPTYwTRuAAj0QqxmYBNM1briFaIzRbi3UiRZ75uNgUHGbfvabgfsHqGaIXYPAMAD8wgC/DOrZ4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=) repeat;
    height: 2000px;
}

footer { background: #ddd;}
* { color: transparent}
```

JS:

```
// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

(** Credit for this code goes to the creator of the JSFiddle)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the `.animate()` class.**

Replace...

```
$('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
```

With...

```
$("header").animate({ top: '-90px' },300);
```

And replace...

```
$('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
```

With...

```
$("header").animate({ top: '10px' },300);
```

**[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/chaffey007/w3jf08hx/27/) is a JSFiddle example using your code.**

*Note that this is just a rough implementation. 
You can play with it and tweak it until it works as you want it to.*

Answer (score 0):

Add transition to the class which you are adding on scroll.

```
.header-maroon{
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```